# How to insert code quality metric - FAKE F#MAKE

Tags: f#, msbuild, f#-interactive, f#-data, f#-fake

I am trying to migrate existing MSBuild file to FAKE . 
I am trying to understand a piece of code but could not find how it is used , and how to implement this in FAKE.And the developer who worked on this MSBuild file has left the company 6-8 months back .So , now I am trying to migrate the existing MSBuild file to FAKE.

This is my MSBuild Code , that I need to implement in FAKE

```
<!-- Code Quality -->
    <BuildFrameworkPath>$(BuildToolsDir)\BuildFramework</BuildFrameworkPath>
    <QualityMetricsMaxComplexityBreaking>10</QualityMetricsMaxComplexityBreaking>   <!-- BREAKS 10 -->
    <QualityMetricsMaxComplexityWarning>9</QualityMetricsMaxComplexityWarning>
    <QualityMetricsLineCoverageBreaking>50</QualityMetricsLineCoverageBreaking><!-- BREAKS 70 -->
    <QualityMetricsLineCoverageWarning>65</QualityMetricsLineCoverageWarning>
    <QualityMetricsSymbolCoverage>70</QualityMetricsSymbolCoverage><!-- 70 -->
    <QualityMetricsBranchCoverage>70</QualityMetricsBranchCoverage><!-- 70 -->
    <QualityMetricsMaxCouplingBreaking>85</QualityMetricsMaxCouplingBreaking> <!-- 40 -->
    <QualityMetricsMaxCouplingWarning>75</QualityMetricsMaxCouplingWarning>
    <QualityMetricsMinMaintainabilityBreaking>35</QualityMetricsMinMaintainabilityBreaking>  <!-- BREAKS 35-->
    <QualityMetricsMinMaintainabilityWarning>30</QualityMetricsMinMaintainabilityWarning>
    <QualityMetricsCouplingExcludeFiles>DependencyInjectionConfiguration</QualityMetricsCouplingExcludeFiles>

    <QualityNDependProjectFilePath>$(BuildRoot)NDepend.ndproj</QualityNDependProjectFilePath>
    <QualityNDependInDirs>$(BuildDir)</QualityNDependInDirs>

    <QualityJsLintScriptsToAnalyse Condition="$(QualityJsLintScriptsToAnalyse) == '' Or $(QualityJsLintScriptsToAnalyse) == '*Undefined*'">$(BuildWebSiteDir)\Scripts\App\*.js</QualityJsLintScriptsToAnalyse>

    <QualityFxCopAssembliesToAnalyse>$(BuildDir)\$(ProjectName)*.dll</QualityFxCopAssembliesToAnalyse>
    <QualityFxCopBreakingRulesProject>$(BuildRoot)Rules.Breaking.fxcop</QualityFxCopBreakingRulesProject>
    <QualityFxCopRulesProject>$(BuildRoot)Rules.fxcop</QualityFxCopRulesProject>

    <QualitySourceMonitorSourceDir>$(BuildSolutionDir)\</QualitySourceMonitorSourceDir>    <!-- be sure to end directory with a "/" -->
```

Is this possible to add quality metric in FAKE . I tried to find out how to do this in FAKE but could not find anything .

If anyone can help me in understanding the existing MSBuild code or in implementing the similar code in FAKE , that would be very helpful.

Comment: I can't even find out which piece of MSBuild *handles* those things: the ONLY Google result for `QualityMetricsMaxComplexityBreaking` is this question. So I can't give you a good answer... but maybe http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/fxcop.html is something to look at?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with downloading executables to run from the command prompt and try to integrate into `Fake` build script with a help of the [ProcessHelper](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-processhelper.html).

From your msbuild code it seems you need next bits:

- For [jslint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/download.htm)
- For [Code Metrics](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48213)
- For [FxCop](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/fxcop.html) there is a direct Fake helper